# Can't see GPU when starting with rc.local (Linux)

Tags: ether, cpp-ethereum, linux

I'm mining ethereum on my Linux Mint mining rig with the claymore miner. I can manually launch my miner with the command line but if I try to start the miner with `/etc/init.d/rc.local` then I get the following error in my log file.

> No AMD OPENCL or NVIDIA CUDA GPUs found, exit

Any ideas why my miner mines just mine when manually launched but it can't see the GPU when launched through `rc.local`? Thanks.